# realloc, heap memory leaks

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind

this is my count and say problem from leetcode solution. But with memory leaks https://leetcode.com/problems/count-and-say/

My makefile

```
build:
    gcc main.c -Wall -g -o main; \
    $(PWD)/main; \
```

My build commands

```
make
```

Or with valgrind:

```
make
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./main
```

Output: (correct, tested)

```
count and say 30 = 3113112221131112311332111213122112311311123112111331121113122112132113121113222112311311221112131221123113112221121113311211131122211211131221131211132221121321132132212321121113121112133221123113112221131112212211131221121321131211132221123113112221131112311332211211133112111311222112111312211311123113322112111312211312111322212321121113121112133221121321132132211331121321132213211231132132211211131221232112111312212221121123222112311311222113111231133211121321321122111312211312111322211213211321322123211211131211121332211231131122211311123113321112131221123113111231121123222112111331121113112221121113122113111231133221121113122113121113221112131221123113111231121123222112111312211312111322212321121113121112131112132112311321322112111312212321121113122122211211232221121321132132211331121321231231121113112221121321132132211322132113213221123113112221133112132123222112111312211312112213211231132132211211131221131211322113321132211221121332211231131122211311123113321112131221123113111231121113311211131221121321131211132221123113112211121312211231131122211211133112111311222112111312211312111322211213211321223112111311222112132113213221133122211311221122111312211312111322212321121113121112131112132112311321322112111312212321121113122122211211232221121321132132211331121321231231121113112221121321132132211322132113213221123113112221133112132123222112111312211312112213211231132132211211131221131211322113321132211221121332211213211321322113311213212312311211131122211213211331121321123123211231131122211211131221131112311332211213211321223112111311222112132113213221123123211231132132211231131122211311123113322112111312211312111322111213122112311311123112112322211213211321322113312211223113112221121113122113111231133221121321132132211331222113321112131122211332113221122112133221123113112221131112311332111213122112311311123112111331121113122112132113121113222112311311221112131221123113112221121113311211131122211211131221131211132221121321132132212321121113121112133221123113112221131112311332111213122112311311123112112322211322311311222113111231133211121312211231131112311211232221121113122113121113222123211211131221132211131221121321131211132221123113112211121312211231131122113221122112133221121321132132211331121321231231121113121113122122311311222113111231133221121113122113121113221112131221123113111231121123222112132113213221133112132123123112111312211322311211133112111312211213211311123113223112111321322123122113222122211211232221121113122113121113222123211211131211121311121321123113213221121113122123211211131221121311121312211213211321322112311311222113311213212322211211131221131211221321123113213221121113122113121113222112131112131221121321131211132221121321132132211331121321232221123113112221131112311322311211131122211213211331121321122112133221121113122113121113222123112221221321132132211231131122211331121321232221121113122113121113222123211211131211121332211213111213122112132113121113222112132113213221232112111312111213322112132113213221133112132123123112111311222112132113311213211221121332211231131122211311123113321112131221123113112221132231131122211211131221131112311332211213211321223112111311222112132113212221132221222112112322211211131221131211132221232112111312111213111213211231131112311311221122132113213221133112132123222112311311222113111231132231121113112221121321133112132112211213322112111312211312111322212321121113121112131112132112311321322112111312212321121113122122211211232221121311121312211213211312111322211213211321322123211211131211121332211213211321322113311213211322132112311321322112111312212321121113122122211211232221121321132132211331121321231231121113112221121321133112132112312321123113112221121113122113111231133221121321132122311211131122211213211321222113222122211211232221123113112221131112311332111213122112311311123112111331121113122112132113121113222112311311221112131221123113112221121113311211131122211211131221131211132221121321132132212321121113121112133221123113112221131112311332111213213211221113122113121113222112132113213221232112111312111213322112132113213221133112132123123112111312211322311211133112111312212221121123222112132113213221133112132123222113223113112221131112311332111213122112311311123112112322211211131221131211132221232112111312111213111213211231132132211211131221131211221321123113213221123113112221131112211322212322211231131122211322111312211312111322211213211321322113311213211331121113122122211211132213211231131122212322211331222113112211
```

From Valgrind

```
==1796== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1796== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et 
al.
==1796== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright 
info
==1796== Command: ./main
==1796== 
==1796== Invalid read of size 1
==1796==    at 0x100000930: countAndSay (main.c:62)
==1796==    by 0x100000ECA: main (main.c:209)
==1796==  Address 0x100df6f80 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 2 
free'd
==1796==    at 0x1000AC2DA: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:829)
==1796==    by 0x100000D10: countAndSay (main.c:172)
==1796==    by 0x100000ECA: main (main.c:209)
==1796==  Block was alloc'd at
==1796==    at 0x1000AB2C5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==1796==    by 0x100000892: countAndSay (main.c:40)
==1796==    by 0x100000ECA: main (main.c:209)
==1796== 
==1796== Invalid read of size 1
==1796==    at 0x10000096B: countAndSay (main.c:73)
==1796==    by 0x100000ECA: main (main.c:209)
==1796==  Address 0x100df6f80 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 2 
free'd
==1796==    at 0x1000AC2DA: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:829)
==1796==    by 0x100000D10: countAndSay (main.c:172)
==1796==    by 0x100000ECA: main (main.c:209)
==1796==  Block was alloc'd at
==1796==    at 0x1000AB2C5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==1796==    by 0x100000892: countAndSay (main.c:40)
==1796==    by 0x100000ECA: main (main.c:209)
==1796== 
==1796== Invalid read of size 1
==1796==    at 0x1000009D7: countAndSay (main.c:89)
==1796==    by 0x100000ECA: main (main.c:209)
==1796==  Address 0x100df6f80 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 2 
free'd
==1796==    at 0x1000AC2DA: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:829)
==1796==    by 0x100000D10: countAndSay (main.c:172)
==1796==    by 0x100000ECA: main (main.c:209)
==1796==  Block was alloc'd at
==1796==    at 0x1000AB2C5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==1796==    by 0x100000892: countAndSay (main.c:40)
==1796==    by 0x100000ECA: main (main.c:209)
==1796== 
==1796== Invalid read of size 16
==1796==    at 0x100655A65: _platform_memchr$VARIANT$Base (in 
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib)
==1796==    by 0x1002E99E9: __sfvwrite (in 
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1796==    by 0x1002F35FE: __vfprintf (in 
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1796==    by 0x100318058: __v2printf (in 
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1796==    by 0x1002EF741: vfprintf_l (in 
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1796==    by 0x1002ED7CA: printf (in 
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1796==    by 0x100000EE0: main (main.c:210)
==1796==  Address 0x10545d410 is 1 bytes after a block of size 4,463 
alloc'd
==1796==    at 0x1000AB2C5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==1796==    by 0x1000AC30C: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:829)
==1796==    by 0x100000C67: countAndSay (main.c:157)
==1796==    by 0x100000ECA: main (main.c:209)
==1796== 
==1796== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1796==    at 0x100655A7D: _platform_memchr$VARIANT$Base (in 
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib)
==1796==    by 0x1002E99E9: __sfvwrite (in 
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1796==    by 0x1002F35FE: __vfprintf (in 
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1796==    by 0x100318058: __v2printf (in 
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1796==    by 0x1002EF741: vfprintf_l (in 
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1796==    by 0x1002ED7CA: printf (in 
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==1796==    by 0x100000EE0: main (main.c:210)
==1796== 
count and say 30 = 3113112221131112311332111213122112311311123112111331121113122112132113121113222112311311221112131221123113112221121113311211131122211211131221131211132221121321132132212321121113121112133221123113112221131112212211131221121321131211132221123113112221131112311332211211133112111311222112111312211311123113322112111312211312111322212321121113121112133221121321132132211331121321132213211231132132211211131221232112111312212221121123222112311311222113111231133211121321321122111312211312111322211213211321322123211211131211121332211231131122211311123113321112131221123113111231121123222112111331121113112221121113122113111231133221121113122113121113221112131221123113111231121123222112111312211312111322212321121113121112131112132112311321322112111312212321121113122122211211232221121321132132211331121321231231121113112221121321132132211322132113213221123113112221133112132123222112111312211312112213211231132132211211131221131211322113321132211221121332211231131122211311123113321112131221123113111231121113311211131221121321131211132221123113112211121312211231131122211211133112111311222112111312211312111322211213211321223112111311222112132113213221133122211311221122111312211312111322212321121113121112131112132112311321322112111312212321121113122122211211232221121321132132211331121321231231121113112221121321132132211322132113213221123113112221133112132123222112111312211312112213211231132132211211131221131211322113321132211221121332211213211321322113311213212312311211131122211213211331121321123123211231131122211211131221131112311332211213211321223112111311222112132113213221123123211231132132211231131122211311123113322112111312211312111322111213122112311311123112112322211213211321322113312211223113112221121113122113111231133221121321132132211331222113321112131122211332113221122112133221123113112221131112311332111213122112311311123112111331121113122112132113121113222112311311221112131221123113112221121113311211131122211211131221131211132221121321132132212321121113121112133221123113112221131112311332111213122112311311123112112322211322311311222113111231133211121312211231131112311211232221121113122113121113222123211211131221132211131221121321131211132221123113112211121312211231131122113221122112133221121321132132211331121321231231121113121113122122311311222113111231133221121113122113121113221112131221123113111231121123222112132113213221133112132123123112111312211322311211133112111312211213211311123113223112111321322123122113222122211211232221121113122113121113222123211211131211121311121321123113213221121113122123211211131221121311121312211213211321322112311311222113311213212322211211131221131211221321123113213221121113122113121113222112131112131221121321131211132221121321132132211331121321232221123113112221131112311322311211131122211213211331121321122112133221121113122113121113222123112221221321132132211231131122211331121321232221121113122113121113222123211211131211121332211213111213122112132113121113222112132113213221232112111312111213322112132113213221133112132123123112111311222112132113311213211221121332211231131122211311123113321112131221123113112221132231131122211211131221131112311332211213211321223112111311222112132113212221132221222112112322211211131221131211132221232112111312111213111213211231131112311311221122132113213221133112132123222112311311222113111231132231121113112221121321133112132112211213322112111312211312111322212321121113121112131112132112311321322112111312212321121113122122211211232221121311121312211213211312111322211213211321322123211211131211121332211213211321322113311213211322132112311321322112111312212321121113122122211211232221121321132132211331121321231231121113112221121321133112132112312321123113112221121113122113111231133221121321132122311211131122211213211321222113222122211211232221123113112221131112311332111213122112311311123112111331121113122112132113121113222112311311221112131221123113112221121113311211131122211211131221131211132221121321132132212321121113121112133221123113112221131112311332111213213211221113122113121113222112132113213221232112111312111213322112132113213221133112132123123112111312211322311211133112111312212221121123222112132113213221133112132123222113223113112221131112311332111213122112311311123112112322211211131221131211132221232112111312111213111213211231132132211211131221131211221321123113213221123113112221131112211322212322211231131122211322111312211312111322211213211321322113311213211331121113122122211211132213211231131122212322211331222113112211
==1796== 
==1796== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1796==     in use at exit: 29,301,895 bytes in 40,712 blocks
==1796==   total heap usage: 80,412 allocs, 39,700 frees, 58,326,719 
bytes allocated
==1796== 
==1796== 72 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 25 of 51
==1796==    at 0x1000ABD72: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:755)
==1796==    by 0x10075A7C2: map_images_nolock (in 
/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==1796==    by 0x10076D4E0: map_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==1796==    by 0x100007C64: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, 
bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info 
const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==1796==    by 0x100007E39: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*) 
(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*) 
(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header 
const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==1796==    by 0x10022571D: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in / 
/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==1796==    by 0x10075A073: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==1796==    by 0x1001AFB34: _os_object_init (in 
/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==1796==    by 0x1001AFB1B: libdispatch_init (in 
/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==1796==    by 0x1000BE9C2: libSystem_initializer (in 
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==1796==    by 0x100019AC5: 
ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) 
(in /usr/lib/dyld)
==1796==    by 0x100019CF5: 
ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in 
/usr/lib/dyld)
==1796== 
==1796== 168 bytes in 56 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 28 
of 51
==1796==    at 0x1000AB2C5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==1796==    by 0x1000AC30C: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:829)
==1796==    by 0x100000D10: countAndSay (main.c:172)
==1796==    by 0x100000ECA: main (main.c:209)
==1796== 
==1796== 570 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 37 of 
51
==1796==    at 0x1000AC2DA: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:829)
==1796==    by 0x100000DCD: countAndSay (main.c:184)
==1796==    by 0x100000ECA: main (main.c:209)
==1796== 
==1796== 1,512 bytes in 378 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 
38 of 51
==1796==    at 0x1000AB2C5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==1796==    by 0x1000AC30C: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:829)
==1796==    by 0x100000DCD: countAndSay (main.c:184)
==1796==    by 0x100000ECA: main (main.c:209)
==1796== 
==1796== 4,462 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 45 
of 51
==1796==    at 0x1000AB2C5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==1796==    by 0x100000867: countAndSay (main.c:29)
==1796==    by 0x100000ECA: main (main.c:209)
==1796== 
==1796== 17,848 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 46 
of 51
==1796==    at 0x1000AB2C5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==1796==    by 0x100000857: countAndSay (main.c:28)
==1796==    by 0x100000ECA: main (main.c:209)
==1796== 
==1796== 19,257 (240 direct, 19,017 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are d 
definitely lost in loss record 48 of 51
==1796==    at 0x1000AB2C5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==1796==    by 0x100000839: countAndSay (main.c:19)
==1796==    by 0x100000ECA: main (main.c:209)
==1796== 
==1796== 61,644 bytes in 406 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 
49 of 51
==1796==    at 0x1000AB2C5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==1796==    by 0x1000AC30C: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:829)
==1796==    by 0x100000C67: countAndSay (main.c:157)
==1796==    by 0x100000ECA: main (main.c:209)
==1796== 
==1796== 80,493 bytes in 379 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 
50 of 51
==1796==    at 0x1000AC2DA: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:829)
==1796==    by 0x100000D10: countAndSay (main.c:172)
==1796==    by 0x100000ECA: main (main.c:209)
==1796== 
==1796== 29,093,648 bytes in 39,299 blocks are definitely lost in loss 
record 51 of 51
==1796==    at 0x1000AC2DA: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:829)
==1796==    by 0x100000DCD: countAndSay (main.c:184)
==1796==    by 0x100000ECA: main (main.c:209)
==1796== 
==1796== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1796==    definitely lost: 29,260,015 bytes in 40,521 blocks
==1796==    indirectly lost: 19,017 bytes in 29 blocks
==1796==      possibly lost: 642 bytes in 4 blocks
==1796==    still reachable: 200 bytes in 6 blocks
==1796==         suppressed: 22,021 bytes in 152 blocks
==1796== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not 
shown.
==1796== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak- 
kinds=all
==1796== 
==1796== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1796== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come 
from
==1796== ERROR SUMMARY: 124 errors from 15 contexts (suppressed: 11 
from 11)
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SEQUENCE_COUNT 30
#define BUFFER_MAX 4462

char* countAndSay(int n) {

    int msc;
    if (n > 0 && n <= 30) {
         msc = MAX_SEQUENCE_COUNT;
    } else {
         fprintf(stderr, "Error: The range for this count and say method is 1...30\n");
         exit(1);
    }

    //Holds the array of sequences
    char **out_buffer = malloc(msc * sizeof(char*));
    //Holds current sequence
    char *out;
    int size = n;

    //Holds previous sequence
    char *prev_chunk = NULL;

    //memory for the counts and says
    int *counts = malloc(BUFFER_MAX*sizeof(int));
    char *says = malloc(BUFFER_MAX*sizeof(char));

    //index into the buffer memory of sequences
    int index = 0;

    //solve iteratively
    while (size > 0) {
        //base condition
        //size counts down to 0, filling chunks, populating the next chunk to be processed
        //filled chunks are placed in the out buffer at the index which is counting 
        if (index == 0) {
            out = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
            out[0] = '1';
            out[1] = '\0';
            prev_chunk = out;
            size -= 1;
            index += 1;
            out_buffer[0] = out;
            continue;
       }

       //from 0 to index - 1 get the chunk to be processed, use it to put together 
    //the count and say chunk for adding to the index slot
        for (int s = 0; s < index; s++) {           
            if (s == 0) {
                prev_chunk = out_buffer[0];
            } else {
                prev_chunk = out_buffer[index];
            }

            //count the length of the current chunk
            int length = 0;
            for (int e = 0; e <= BUFFER_MAX; e++) {
                if (prev_chunk[e]) {
                   length += 1;
                } else {
                   break;
                }
            }

            //The count of says at each iteration
            int count = 0;

            //say is a char byte from the previous chunk memory
            char say = prev_chunk[0];
            //skip is used in the iteration process 
            int skip = 0;

            //The idx into memory for the counts and says
            int idx = 0;

            //iteratively generate the count and say chunk for this index
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (skip > 0) {
                    if (i < length - 1) {
                        say = prev_chunk[i + 1];
                    }
                    skip -= 1;
                    continue;
                }
                if (prev_chunk[i] == say) {
                    count += 1;
                    counts[idx] = count;
                    says[idx] = say;
                    //if at the end of the iteration add one
                    //as a terminator for the counts, says, pairs
                    if (i == length - 1) {
                        idx += 1;
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    count = 0;
                    if (i == length - 1) {
                        //finish off
                        idx += 1;
                        count += 1;
                        counts[idx] = count;
                        says[idx] = prev_chunk[i];
                        say = says[idx];
                        idx += 1;
                    } else {
                        idx += 1;
                        count += 1;
                        counts[idx] = count;
                        says[idx] = prev_chunk[i];
                        char next_say = prev_chunk[i + 1];
                        say = prev_chunk[i];
                        //Takes care of itself with idx
                        if (next_say != prev_chunk[i]) {
                            count = 0;
                            continue;
                        } 

                        int y = i;
                        while (next_say == say && y < length -1) {
                            count += 1;
                            //dont need to up the index because we are counting howmany there are
                            says[idx] = say;
                            counts[idx] = count;
                            //skip because this is the next loop 
                            skip += 1;
                            //subtract 1 because we want this to be in the final index slot
                            //count because we added an index
                            y += 1;
                            next_say = prev_chunk[y + 1];
                        }
                        idx += 1;
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }
            }      

            //Could have just generated the sequence from above but felt like doing this manually at the time
            //If I get around to it ill change  
            int chunk_offset = 0;
            char *temp = NULL;
            for (int u = 0; u < idx; u++) {
                 int c = counts[u];
                 //TODO: factor out or use sprintf, or maybe not, maybe this is just faster
                 char cc;
                 if (c >= 10) {
                     cc = 'A' + c - 10;
                 } else {
                     cc = '0' + c;
                 }

                 char say = says[u];
                 if (u == idx - 1) {
                     temp = realloc(temp, chunk_offset + 3);
                     if (chunk_offset > 0) {
                        for (int y = 0; y < chunk_offset; y++) {
                            temp[y] = out[y];
                        }

                        temp[chunk_offset] = cc;
                        temp[chunk_offset + 1] = say;
                        temp[chunk_offset + 2] = '\0';
                    } else {
                        temp[0] = cc;
                        temp[1] = say;
                        temp[2] = '\0';
                    }

                    out = realloc(out, chunk_offset + 3);
                    out = temp;
                    temp = NULL;
                    free(temp);
                } else {
                    temp = realloc(temp, chunk_offset + 2);
                    for (int ii = 0; ii < chunk_offset; ii++) {
                        temp[ii] = out[ii];
                    }
                    temp[chunk_offset] = cc;
                    temp[chunk_offset + 1] = say;
                    chunk_offset += 2;
                    out = realloc(out, chunk_offset + 2);
                    out = temp;
                    temp = NULL;
                    free(temp);
               }
           }        
         out_buffer[index] = out;
         out = NULL;
         free(out);
       }
     index += 1;
     size -= 1;
   }

   free(prev_chunk);
   prev_chunk = NULL;
   free(counts);
   counts = NULL;
   free(says);
   says = NULL;

   return out_buffer[n - 1];
 }

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *cs = countAndSay(30);
    printf("count and say 30 = %s\n", cs);
}
```

I know it is not the best algorithm but it works. It is my understanding that realloc can be used in a way to avoid
piling up malloc'd memory to the heap inside of loop's kinda like this which works. My suspicion is that by doing so it moves memory into places that are not easily found and free'd. Am I on the right path with that line of thinking? Simple realloc

```
char *e = NULL;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    e = realloc(e, i + 1);
    if (i == 9) {
        e[i] = '\0';
    } else {
        e[i] = 'e';
    }
}
printf("%s\n", e);
free(e);
```

Yields from valgrind:

```
==4421== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4421==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4421==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4421==      possibly lost: 72 bytes in 3 blocks
==4421==    still reachable: 200 bytes in 6 blocks
==4421==         suppressed: 22,021 bytes in 152 blocks
```

I have been running this with valgrind trying to pin down the leaking issue. I have also seen solution such as this and tried them with no luck: ["Pointer being freed was not allocated." error after malloc, realloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578340/pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-error-after-malloc-realloc).

I believe the main problem I am having here is that I malloc "out" the first time. After that I realloc it each time in the loop(s). Valgrind is giving the biggest leaks at line main.c:184 "out = realloc(out, chunk_offset + 2);". It seems like realloc is just deciding to put that memory somewhere in the heap and I cant get to it. I know the address can change from a realloc, but I still havent been able to get at it. How can I get definitely lost down to 0 in my countandsay.

Comment: Also look at what you're doing with `out`:  You're saving it in `out_buffer[index]`, then you're freeing it.  That means the value you stored in `out_buffer[index]` has been freed and has no possible use.

Comment: what was the result with valgrind ? you don't say. Of course `out_buffer[index] = out;  free(out); ` will produce a problem when you will reuse the freed memory

Comment: Using realloc should not cause a problem with freeing out where I have, I verified

Comment: @GregPrice: notice that you don't have to use  `cmake`. For a single-file `myprog.c` C program you can just compile it on the command line: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g myprog.c -o myprogbin`. You could use many other [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation), notably [GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) by writing your simple [Makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile). In your case, `cmake` is overkill

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE] (with a `main` and give the compilation command). And read more about [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).

Comment: Ok I will add my compilation process above and definitely read through the links provided. My mistake I should have been more clear I am not using clion or cmake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with this block:

```
             if (u == idx - 1) {
                 temp = realloc(temp, chunk_offset + 3);
                 if (chunk_offset > 0) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < chunk_offset; y++) {
                        temp[y] = out[y];
                    }

                    temp[chunk_offset] = cc;
                    temp[chunk_offset + 1] = say;
                    temp[chunk_offset + 2] = '\0';
                } else {
                    temp[0] = cc;
                    temp[1] = say;
                    temp[2] = '\0';
                }

                out = realloc(out, chunk_offset + 3);
                //    *** MEMORY LEAK ***
                out = temp;
                temp = NULL;
                //    NOT NEEDED
                free(temp);
            } else {
                temp = realloc(temp, chunk_offset + 2);
                for (int ii = 0; ii < chunk_offset; ii++) {
                    temp[ii] = out[ii];
                }
                temp[chunk_offset] = cc;
                temp[chunk_offset + 1] = say;
                chunk_offset += 2;
                out = realloc(out, chunk_offset + 2);
                //    *** MEMORY LEAK ***
                out = temp;
                temp = NULL;
                //    NOT NEEDED
                free(temp);
           }
```

In both parts of the `if`, you expand the size of `out`, but then you immediately overwrite `out` with the value of `temp`, leaking the memory that `out` was pointing to.

Since `temp` contains the values you want, you no longer need what's in `out`, so get rid of the `realloc` on `out` and instead `free` what was there previously.  Also, there's no need to `free(temp)` since it points to NULL, and you can replace the `realloc` calls with `malloc` since `temp` will always be NULL at that point:

```
             if (u == idx - 1) {
                 temp = malloc(chunk_offset + 3);
                 if (chunk_offset > 0) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < chunk_offset; y++) {
                        temp[y] = out[y];
                    }

                    temp[chunk_offset] = cc;
                    temp[chunk_offset + 1] = say;
                    temp[chunk_offset + 2] = '\0';
                } else {
                    temp[0] = cc;
                    temp[1] = say;
                    temp[2] = '\0';
                }
            } else {
                temp = malloc(chunk_offset + 2);
                for (int ii = 0; ii < chunk_offset; ii++) {
                    temp[ii] = out[ii];
                }
                temp[chunk_offset] = cc;
                temp[chunk_offset + 1] = say;
                chunk_offset += 2;
           }
           free(out);
           out = temp;
```

Then you have this at the bottom of your `for` loop:

```
for (int s = 0; s < index; s++) {
     ...
     out_buffer[index] = out;
     out = NULL;
     free(out);
}
```

You overwrite the contents of `out_buffer[index]` on each iteration which leaks memory.  You'll need to `free` the old contents first, and also get rid of the unneeded `free(out)` at the end since it contains NULL at that point.  This also means you need to initialize `out_buffer[index]` to NULL before entering the loop.

```
out_buffer[index] = NULL;
for (int s = 0; s < index; s++) {
     ...
     free(out_buffer[index]);
     out_buffer[index] = out;
     out = NULL;
}
```

Then you have an issue here:

```
    if (index == 0) {
        out = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
        out[0] = '1';
        out[1] = '\0';
        prev_chunk = out;
        size -= 1;
        index += 1;
        out_buffer[0] = out;
        continue;
   }
```

Which fails to set `out` to NULL before the next iteration of the loop, which will result in `out_buffer[0]` getting free'ed and subsequently reading from free'ed memory.  So add that here:

```
    if (index == 0) {
        out = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
        out[0] = '1';
        out[1] = '\0';
        prev_chunk = out;
        size -= 1;
        index += 1;
        out_buffer[0] = out;
        out = NULL;
        continue;
   }
```

Then at the end:

```
free(prev_chunk);
prev_chunk = NULL;
free(counts);
counts = NULL;
free(says);
says = NULL;

return out_buffer[n - 1];
```

You don't want to `free(prev_chunk);` since it points to an old copy of `out` that was already free'ed.  You're also not freeing `out_buffer` or any of the strings it points to.  You don't want to free the string you return, of course, so skip that one:

```
char *rval = out_buffer[n - 1];
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
     free(out_buffer[i]);
}
free(out_buffer);
free(counts);
free(says);

return rval;
```

Finally, make sure you `free` the result of this function once `main` is done with it:

```
char *cs = countAndSay(30);
printf("count and say 30 = %s\n", cs);
free(cs);
```

Now you have a clean run through valgrind with no memory leaks or invalid read/write/free errors.

On a side note, there are a lot of inefficiencies in this code.  On each iteration of the outer `while` loop, you generate the entire list from 1 to the current value of `n`.  So on the first iteration you calculate n=1, then on the next you calculate n=1,2, then on the next you calculate n=1,2,3, etc.

You only need one loop here.  That also means you don't have to reuse the current value of `out_buffer` but can instead just reference the previous one.  I'll leave those changes as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Ok this awesome! I had a couple things happen when I made the edits. First I still have a leak 61,644 bytes in 406 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 42 of 42 at line 163 or temp = malloc(chunk_offset + 2);. Now, I also have a segfault for larger sequence numbers if I free out the second time as such free(out);
     out_buffer[index] = out;
     out = NULL; These two seem contingent. Thoughts? (Ps The code is far from optimal I know, the out is overkill since I have the sequence just trying to get a better understanding of what is going on with memory)

Comment: @GregPrice There was a typo in that part.  It should be `free(out_buffer[index]);` instead of `free(out);`  As for the segfault for larger numbers, make sure that `BUFFER_MAX` is large enough for the sequences you're storing.

Comment: Ahh. Yes your the man! Ok, I accidently clicked the bounty over to the answer Im contacting so about giving you the bounty

Comment: will keep you up to date

Comment: We cannot modify or move bounties once they've been awarded, and there is no way to undo this action.

Regards,
Stack Overflow Team
No response to follow up. Looks like there is injustice here but someday soon, not sure when, Ill post another bounty and wait for a really good answer

Comment: Ill be able to award a bounty after an unspecified period of time

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you are freeing the pointer you allocated at the end of the loop, even though you saved the pointer for posterity or something.

Based on this code, I'd say you want to do several things:

1. Don't free memory you're not done with just because you're done with the variable that was holding onto its pointer.
2. Change this to malloc rather than realloc, because you clearly are wanting a separate space for each pass through the loop.
3. Get an editor that will help you with your indentation, or learn to configure the editor you use to help you with your indentation.  This might sound like an opinion, but this looks like the sort of problem I've found is much easier to diagnose if your indentation means something.  It'll probably also help you with getting help, because few expert programmers want to deal with inconsistent indentation like that.  It's my impression I'm one of the few people who sees something like that and decides to pop it into vim, and then type `=gg` to reformat everything to be reasonable.  (Note: if you don't use vi, nvi, or vim, don't use it just because I do - all three of those editors have a huge learning curve, and most programming editors can do the same sort of thing.)

And just to reinforce the last point: Once I reformatted it to have consistent indentation, the problem jumped out at me.  Tom almost got it, but I think he thought that was the end of your function, rather than the end of your loop.

Comment: To the first two points... Im fairly new to actual str8 c and have used it on and off in academia and leetcode and a bit professionally. Objective-C I have used a lot  but there are the abstractions. Anyways, here, If I am freeing the returned outbuffer after the function valgrind is showing the outs are kept around as expected. Is this acceptable C practice then? Also, thanks for the note about the editor I use vi and Ill look at =gg. I havent really found a need yet for a large IDE as the projects in C I do are fairly small. I dabbled with C lion, but that has all the Cmake overhead, os dp's

Comment: using realloc actually free'd up the heap more than malloc. Thoughts?

Comment: @GregPrice: you don't have to use  `cmake`. Just compile your single-file command line on the command line in a terminal, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g yourprog.c -o progbin`. And you should at least use [indent(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/indent.1.html) to format your C file. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54041928/841108) answer.

Comment: free does not work on the variable that is passed in, it works on the contents of that variable.  If you've copied the contents of that variable somewhere else and then you free it, leaving the contents at that other location, that other location is now a time bomb.  valgrind should complain about it, but I won't guarantee that it will.  How quickly that time bomb goes off depends on more factors than I could probably name.  It could work on one system or for one user for years, and blow up for another every time.

Comment: Ok two things. 1. Freeing the new location of the variable should free it from the heap correct? 2. I believe the main problem I am having here is that I malloc out the first time. After that I realloc it each time in the loop. Valgrind is giving the biggest leaks at line main.c:184 "out = realloc(out, chunk_offset + 2);". It seems like realloc is just deciding to put that memory somewhere in the heap and I cant get to it. I know the address can change from a realloc, but I still havent been able to get at it. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If we look at how the Look-and-Say algorithm works, we find that each character (or a sequence of same characters) produces a character pair in the output. Thus, if the length of the input is *N* characters, the length of the output is at most 2*N* characters.

Let's look at a function that generates the *next* string in the Look-and-Say sequence:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *look_and_say(const char *src)
{
    const size_t  srclen = (src) ? strlen(src) : 0;
    char         *dst;

    if (srclen < 1) {
        /* Nothing to look or say. */
        return NULL;
    }

    /* The result can be up to twice as long as the source,
       plus the string-terminating nul char. */
    dst = malloc(2*srclen + 1);
    if (!dst) {
        /* Not enough memory for the result. */
        return NULL;
    }

    {
        const char *const  end = src + srclen;
        char              *pos = dst;

        while (src < end) {
            const char *const was = src;

            /* Skip repeated source characters. */
            do {
                src++;
            } while (src < end && *src == *was);

            /* The longest allowed sequence is 9. */
            if ((size_t)(src - was) > 9) {
                free(dst);
                return NULL;
            }

            *(pos++) = '0' + (size_t)(src - was);
            *(pos++) = *was;
        }

        *pos = '\0';

        return dst;
    }
}
```

The above does not care what the input string is; you can supply it anything. If the input string is NULL or empty, it will return NULL.  If it cannot allocate memory (twice the length of the input string, plus one char for the string-terminating nul `'\0'` character), it returns NULL.  If a character repeats more than 9 times in a row, the function returns NULL.

The Look-and-Say sequence is [OEIS A005150](http://oeis.org/A005150) at the On-line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, which points out that R. G. Wilson v showed in 2004 that only digits `1`, `2`, and `3` exist in the sequence. Thus, for the integer sequence, the one could open-code the test whether a digit repeats (two or three times).

The length of each term in that sequence forms another integer sequence, [OEIS A005341](http://oeis.org/A005341). It turns out that the length of term *i* is something like 1.56 × 1.304<sup>*i*</sup> (i.e, `(size_t)(1.0 + 1.56*exp(0.26544*i)`). The 30th term in the sequence is 4462 characters long.

If we wanted to generate each value in the sequence, we could use a single dynamically managed buffer (to hold the value being generated), and save a *duplicate* of each result:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *sdup(const char *src, const size_t len)
{
    char *s;

    s = malloc(len + 1);
    if (!s) {
        fprintf(stderr, "sdup(): Not enough memory for a duplicate of %zu-character string.\n", len);
        return NULL;
    }

    memcpy(s, src, len);
    s[len] = '\0';

    return s;
}

/* Initial buffer size, at least 1. */
#ifndef  INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE
#define  INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE  1
#endif

char **look_and_say(const size_t  count)
{
    char  **table;
    char   *src, *end;
    char   *dst, *pos;
    size_t  len, max = INITIAL_BUFFER_SIZE;
    size_t  i, k;

    if (count < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "look_and_say(): Count is less than 1.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Allocate memory for the array of pointers. */
    table = calloc(count + 2, sizeof *table);
    if (!table) {
        fprintf(stderr, "look_and_say(): Not enough memory for an array of %zu strings.\n", count);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* First and last entries are NULLs; sentinels, if you will. */
    table[0] = NULL;
    table[count + 1] = NULL;

    /* Allocate memory for the dynamic buffer. */
    dst = malloc(max);
    if (!dst) {
        fprintf(stderr, "look_and_say(): Not enough memory for a %zu-character work buffer.\n", max);
        free(table);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* The sequence starts with "1". */
    dst[0] = '1';
    len = 1;

    /* Save that. */
    table[1] = sdup(dst, len);

    /* Loop over the rest of the entries to be generated. */
    for (i = 2; i <= count; i++) {
        /* The source is the last item in the sequence. */
        src = table[i - 1];
        end = table[i - 1] + len;

        /* Ensure we have enough room for the next value in the sequence. */
        if (2*len > max) {
            /* TODO: Better growth policy! */
            max = 2*len;

            pos = realloc(dst, max);
            if (!pos) {
                fprintf(stderr, "look_and_say(): Not enough memory to grow work buffer to %zu chars.\n", max);
                free(dst);
                for (k = 1; k < i; k++)
                    free(table[k]);
                free(table);
                return NULL;
            }
            dst = pos;
        } else
            pos = dst;

        /* Source is [src, end[. pos is the next position in work buffer. */
        while (src < end) {
            const int  nc = *(src++);
            int        nn = '1';

            /* Skip if source is repeated twice or three times. */
            if (*src == nc) {
                src++;
                nn++;   /* 2 */
                if (*src == nc) {
                    src++;
                    nn++; /* 3 */
                }
            }

            *(pos++) = nn;
            *(pos++) = nc;
        }

        /* Length of the generated value. */
        len = (size_t)(pos - dst);

        /* Save to table. */
        table[i] = sdup(dst, len);
        if (!table[i]) {
            free(dst);
            for (k = 1; k < i; k++)
                free(table[i]);
            free(table);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    /* Dynamic buffer is no longer needed. */
    free(dst);

    return table;
}

#ifndef  LIMIT
#define  LIMIT  30
#endif

int main(void)
{
    char **sequence;
    size_t i;

    sequence = look_and_say(LIMIT);
    if (!sequence)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    for (i = 1; i <= LIMIT; i++)
        printf("%zu. %s\n", i, sequence[i]);

    for (i = 1; i <= LIMIT; i++)
        free(sequence[i]);
    free(sequence);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

At this point, we must note that we already have an *O*(*N*) algorithm for generating the next value in the sequence, were *N* is the length of the previous value. Getting better than linear performance requires a better algorithm, but as far as I know, there is no trivial better-than-linear solution known for this.

We can optimize the above code at the code level, of course; but its time complexity is already quite good.

If we wanted to "cheat", we could observe that the lengths of the first thirty terms in the sequence are 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 6, 8, 10, 14, 20, 26, 34, 46, 62, 78, 102, 134, 176, 226, 302, 408, 528, 678, 904, 1182, 1540, 2012, 2606, 3410, 4462. This means that if we allocate enough memory for the pointers and 19019 characters (the sum of the lengths + 30 for the end-of-string characters), we only need a single allocation. If we reserve the zeroth pointer for a NULL, then that allocation would be `malloc(19019 + 31 * sizeof (char *))`.

However, continuing along that path, we end up with the following code, or something very similar:

```
static const char  term_1[] = "1";
static const char  term_2[] = "11";
static const char  term_3[] = "21";
static const char  term_4[] = "1211";
static const char  term_5[] = "111221";
/* term_6[] through term_30[] omitted */

static const char *sequence[31] = {
    NULL,
    term_1,  term_2,  term_3,  term_4,  term_5,
    term_6,  term_7,  term_8,  term_9,  term_10,
    term_11, term_12, term_13, term_14, term_15,
    term_16, term_17, term_18, term_19, term_20,
    term_21, term_22, term_23, term_24, term_25,
    term_26, term_27, term_28, term_29, term_30
};
```

This generates about 19 KiB of read-only (immutable) data in the generated binary. That would not be a problem even on many microcontrollers, if that sequence was somehow crucial for the operation.

If memory use is an issue, could trivially pack each individual digits in two bits, keeping access time reasonable, in which case only about 5 KiB of memory is used for the data.

Comment: This is excellent info and code. A little over my head currently in c, Im trying to figure out my memory issues currently......

Comment: @GregPrice: I hoped that if I showed how I would solve the problem, and how few allocations and how simply and yet efficiently one can implement the dynamic memory management, you could compare to your own, and that way fix the issues.  I usually approach solving overall problems from a modular approach: building self-contained operations first (just like here, the *generate-next-value-in-the-sequence* function), rather than attacking the whole overall problem all at once. [...]

Comment: @GregPrice: As you can see, it is rather compact. (If you'd like to see it described in detail, say as pseudocode, or perhaps written in another language like Python for comparison -- the Rosetta stone approach --, let me know.) Working on such small piece of code at a time, and getting it working right, saves time and effort.  I usually also wrap it in an unit test program, and verify the function works correctly for known input-output pairs, but also that it fails gracefully for unexpected/bad inputs. That way, I know it works, and do not need to keep the details in my mind. [...]

Comment: @GregPrice: Next, I go back to theory, and look at the algorithm at the, well, algorithmic level. (I warmly recommend Weiss' *Algorithm Analysis in C* from 1997/2001, if you can find a copy.) If I find or suspect a different algorithm is better, I redo the unit test program, and compare them. [...]

Comment: @GregPrice: Then, when I am satisfied that the algorithm I am using is sound (as an approach to solve the overall problem), I write a preliminary unit test for solving the overall problem using the functions I've already written.  This part here I basically guessed at, and instead just assumed that the first 30 terms in the sequence were needed for some other task, say a game or such.

Comment: @GregPrice: So, I did not really answer your stated question (others did that already), but attempted to help you find a way to implement a solution to this and other similar questions yourself, showing the approach that has worked well for me thus far. (Not just to help you in particular, but others working on similar issues and finding your question.) I do appreciate the bounty, but what I really am interested in, is suggestions on how I could do my part better. (If you look at my answer history, I often do what I did here; I'm not after reputation, just to help others learn.)

Comment: @GregPrice: Thus, if you have **any** questions on especially the first function (details on how and why it works, or why I wrote some snippet the way I did), I would appreciate if you asked them in a comment, so that I can not only elaborate those details in this "answer", but also construct better answers in the future.  (I am rather vehement in that there exists enough bad C code already, and am very keen on helping new C programmers do better.)

Comment: I will get back to you on that and yes C code can be bad so thanks for the help